# How to send digits and wait time in twilio call using Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, twilio

I am trying to make a call and send some digits. The outcome i want to achieve is the call should be forwarded from my business number to mobile number.

I used below code,

```
@call = @client.account.calls.create(
    :from => 'xxxx', # twilio_number,
    :to => 'xxxx', # RACF number,
    :send_digits => "xxxx", # Business number
    :timeout => "3",
    :send_digits => "xxxx", # pin
    :timeout => "3",
    :send_digits => "*xx", # option for forwarding
    :timeout => "3",
    :send_digits => "xx", # confirm option
    :timeout => "3",
    :send_digits => "xxxxx", # destination number to which call should be forwarded
    :method => "GET"
    :url => "http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml" # Fetch instructions from this URL when the call connects
  )
```

I am using timeout to take pause. Please let me know how to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You're almost there, but `send_digits` should have a long string with the digits and the character 'w' to represent the pauses.

According to [the documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/number#attributes-sendDigits) each `w` represents 0.5 second, so you should change your code to be the follow:

```
@call = @client.account.calls.create(
    :from => 'xxxx', # twilio_number,
    :to => 'xxxx', # RACF number,
    :send_digits => "+1234567www12345www*123www",
    :url => "http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml" # Fetch instructions from this URL when the call connects
  )
```

Where `+1234567www12345www*123www` would represent:

- Business number
- 1.5 second pause
- pin
- another 1.5 second pause
- option for forwarding
- etc...

So all in one line without any timeouts.

Hope this helps you

Comment: I am trying to send digits through twilio as well. I get a error `Twilio::REST::RequestError: SendDigits must be less than 32 characters long` whenI try to send one continous string.

Comment: Maybe I can use twiml instead of sending the files as post params.

Comment: @Saurabh have a look at Megan's response here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36320949/twilio-rest-api-http-400-error-senddigits-must-be-less-than-32-characters-long

Comment: Got this working by using the way Megan suggested. The steps which I performed in my question, i implemeted them using twiml and set the file generated in the url parameter of the code.

@call = @client.account.calls.create(
    :from => 'xxxx', # twilio_number,
    :to => 'xxxx', # RACF number,
    :send_digits => "+1234567www12345www*123www",
    :url => "URL" # The file at this url had the xml code that did the work of sending digits, entering pin, etc.
  )